# Current Java Connection Pool Status

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am embarking on a project in Java, it is a desktop DUI app, about 25-30 daily users on the same LAN as the database, CRUD all day long.

So I started looking in to Java connection pool libs, and I am confused as to the current state of the players,  C3P0 and  DBCP are both reported as being dead and alive, but the web presence seems dead.  BoneCP states it is better than those two but that it is dead and should not be used.

So what is a good, live and supported connection pool lib for Java?  If it matters the DB is SQLServer.

Thanks

Comment: Hikaricp, Tomcat Jdbc Pool, dbcp2

Comment: I would support Hikaricp, and not DBCP2. I have already faced multiple issues in my application, and couldn't resolve since a year. Here are the links. [Issue 1] - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126965/java-code-to-get-lost-active-db-connection-back-to-the-connection-pool) [Issue 2] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865460/close-all-the-active-connection-in-dbcp2).

Answer (score 0):

As someone who works for a large company I can tell you that C3P0 is still very much in use even if there is not much development on the project.  The community that uses it is still fairly large, so it is likely you will find people to help if there are any problems.  C3P0 is also the database connection pool used in the JBoss tutorial.