# Java code to get lost active DB Connection back to the connection pool

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am facing connection leakage problem with DBCP2.

I went though all the code base and have closed/released the connections wherever required.

I have also run Sonar, but no connection leakages were reported.

Finally I have decide to write a java based executor service which will close or return the DB connections back to the pool periodically.
The service should run once in 2 days.

Can someone help with the code to close the connections which are not returned to pool?

Comment: That is hardly a solution. Also what symptoms do you experience?

Comment: I completely agree with you, but I need to find a quick fix, that would solve this problem. Its already running in prod, so the fix can be temporary unless we find all the connection leakages. The problem is once the number of active connections reaches its max level, the pool runs out of connection and the application is not able to get more connections for DB interaction.

Comment: Then you still have a leak somewhere... Also you generally shouldn't be messing around with a `Connection` directly but rather use the `JdbcTemplate` to execute queries. And no doing `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection` is not using the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: I am aware that there can be leakages in the code which I am not able to figure out at the moment as the code is very large, and I cannot go check each file. There are around 1k DAO classes. So it will take huge time to look for leakages manually. I am using springs JDBCTemplate, and apache DBCP2 Datasource.

Comment: Ditch DBCP2 and switch to HikariCP. It has leak detection and will log that as well as automatically return leaked connections to the pool.

Comment: I would prefer c3p0. I recent joined this organisation. And this application of theirs is running for more than 4 years. So moving to new/other tech would require more dev/test/ time.

Comment: c3p0 is old as well and not maintained anymore. Why would switching a datasource require testing? You could enable abandoned connection testing on the connection pool see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html on how to enable. This will then reclaim/close connection automatically. However I would strongly suggest moving to HikariCP we moved from C3P0 to Hikari and got improved times and better pool management. (It is also the default pool used by Spring Boot nowadays).

Comment: I would love to move to newer technologies, but there are lot of approvals needed in my org. Regarding the DBCP2 configurations, I have implemented those long back, the performance have definitely improved but the there are still few connection leakages.

Comment: Did you configure idle connection checking and abandoned connection validation? Also make sure you enabled check when idle. Do you really have connection leaks or do you have stale connections... DBCP is a rather poor connection pool implementation in my experience. Regarding permissions -> (to quote Grace Hopper a Pioneer in our field) : **if you've got a good idea, and it's a contribution, I want you to go ahead and DO IT. It is much easier to apologize than it is to get permission.**.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I would implement this and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @M.Deinum As far as I'm aware, C3P0 is still maintained, just not very actively anymore (I assume Steve Waldman thinks it is mature and stable enough).

Comment: The last release was 3 years ago (according to GitHub) so not sure how maintained that is. Nonetheless we switched from C3P0 and had better results in our app with HikariCP (faster, less hiccups etc). But YMMV...

Comment: Whatever it is, I need a quick fix for the problem I am facing.

Comment: I am not sure as how could somebody help without looking at code? Also, if developer is doing all he could do in terms of closing DB connection ( as you have said ) & it happens to be some defect in pool library then also how can somebody help ? Writing external service for this task is what I am hearing for first time, upgrading or changing library seems easier option.

Comment: @SabirKhan - Writing an external service is a temporary solution what I need. Closing the connection or configuring the DBCP2 Pool in a optimized way is what we all already know.